# How to check and replace null value in C#

Tags: c#, null

Anyone can guide me a way to check and replace null values in strList with String message "NO DATA" or allow them in dtList. 
Because when I met a null value in this List,it show an error like "There is no row at position..."

```
private DataTable getSomething1(String text){
    DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
    ...
    ...
    return dtb;
}

...

protected void buttonCheck_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e){
    List<DataTable> strList = new List<DataTable>(){
        getSomething(txtInput.Text),
        getSomething2(txtInput.Text),
        getSomething3(txtInput.Text),
        ...                
    };
}
```

I used C# in Webform.
Plz, help me to fix this code or guide me a way to solve it. 
Thanks in advance.

@tech, @ riffnl: Finally I get all of your ideas and it really work now. Anw, thanks all pro here for advices. So, this is my solution ^^

```
private String ConvertNullToEmptyString(DataTable element)
    {
        if (element.Rows.Count > 0) //just add this condition here
        {
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(element.Rows[0]["FullName"]))
                return (string)element.Rows[0]["FullName"] + " ";
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }
        return "NO DATA";
    }

protected void ....(){
     List<DataTable> strList = new List<DataTable>(){
       GetItem1(txtName.Text),   //private DataTable GetItem1(String t)
       GetItem2(txtName.Text),   //...           
     };

    txtGrD_D.Text = ConvertNullToEmptyString(strList[0]);
    txtGrM_D.Text = ConvertNullToEmptyString(strList[1]);
}
```

Comment: If row 0 is null, then you can't parse it into string, so either check for null there or check for the row count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a datatable I assume you're not talking about NULL (or nill), but DBNull..
Change your function ConvertNullToEmptyString like this:

```
private String ConvertNullToEmptyString(DataTable element){ 
  if (element.Rows[0]["Fullname"] == DBNull.Value || element.Rows[0]["Fullname"] == null) {
    return "NO DATA";
  } else {
    return element.Rows[0]["Fullname"].ToString();
  }
}
```

as requested: new sample;

```
// a list of datatables each containing 1 row, wasn't that the point of datatables
    // anyway -- I think you don't have any rows, so let's try this:
    private String ConvertNullToEmptyString(DataTable element)
    {
        if (element.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return "NO DATA";
        }
        if (element.Rows[0]["Fullname"] == DBNull.Value || element.Rows[0]["Fullname"] == null)
        {
            return "NO DATA";
        }
        else
        {
            return element.Rows[0]["Fullname"].ToString();
        }
    } 
    protected void Test()
    {
        List<DataTable> strList = new List<DataTable>(){ 
           GetItem("test1"),   //private DataTable GetItem1(String t) 
           GetItem("test2")   //...            
         };
        txtGrD_D.Text = ConvertNullToEmptyString(strList[0]);
    }
```

Comment: if that's is the correct answer mark the checkmark green in front of the answer to mark it as correct - it'll improve your acceptrating.

Comment: i understand your solution. its sound logically. i change a little bit to suite my situation. but i dont know why it still be... "There is no row at position 0.". hix

Comment: can you point out my error. I've already edited my post on above like your idea

Comment: Yah. I get your ideas and do it in my way. Your idea help me find the solution in this way much. Thanks pro

Comment: I am not sure but Instead of: if (element.Rows.Count == 0) try using: if (element.Rows.Any())

Answer (score 8):

You can use C#'s [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) **??**:

```
string s = null;
s = s ?? "NO DATA";
// s now equals "NO DATA";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way by using String.IsNullOrEmpty.
I double a cell in dataTable can be null.

```
        //creating an example table with one row (no data inisde):
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add("");
        string str = ConvertNullToEmptyString(table);

    //method to check for string:
    private String ConvertNullToEmptyString(DataTable element)
    {
        String s = element.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "NO DATA" : s);
    }
```

Comment: indeed it can't be null it can be DBNull though

Answer (score 0):

If the error is "There is no row at position...", then I guess the probelm is not that a string is null, but it is, instead, that you are trying to access a row that does not exist in the datatable.

In particular, in the line :

```
String s = element.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
```

You try to access the first row of the datatable.
What if the datatable is empty ? You get an error!
So you should check if the datatable contains rows with something like this:

```
if (element.Rows.Count >0)
```

---

Answer to you comment:
 yes we can. 
modify your:

```
foreach (DataTable element in strList)
```

into something like:

```
foreach (DataTable element in strList)     
    {          
    if (element.Rows.Count>0)
        {
        if(strList.Any(item => item == null))          
            {                
          ConvertNullToEmptyStringelement);                                                 
            }
        txtItem1.Text = mytext ;          
        .....
        }
    else
        {
        txtItem1.Text = "No Data";          
        }      
    }
```

This is as far as I can go without modifying too much your program structure.

Comment: yup. this row does not exist in the datatable. it's empty so i wanna allow them to be a string message = "NO DATA" and i dont know how to do it. can we do it, pro ?

Comment: yes: look into the answer, I've edited it with a possible solution

Comment: can you point out my error. I've already edited my post on above  like you said

Comment: probably the error is in the line: `txtGrM_D.Text = strList[1].Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString(); ` Here you are referencing a datatable (strList[1]) where you have not checked if there is at least one row.

Comment: uk. i got it. i've already find a way to checked it before replace it. thanks pro